# Is getting into the actuarial profession haram or halal?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I haven't seen this posted anywhere in this forum. Is getting into the actuarial profession halal or haram?

Please elaborate on your reasons. I want to know because I graduated from an actuarial science master's degree. If it is haram, do I have to unlearn what I learned in college?

Comment: Why do you think it could be haram?

Comment: Many people say insurance is haram...actuaries mainly work for insurance companies..they study bonds, futures, etc..most of it are based on interest. Google it if you need more info..